# How to create an installer file for an application created in Netbeans(java)?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have started creating small applications in Java using Net-beans, i was trying to make installer file for the application as we do in .Net. I tried many thing and not succeeded. Somebody please help me.

Comment: Which "many things" did you try and how did it go?

Comment: i tried making executable jar file, then creating batch files..etc. but nothing could create an installer file.

Comment: You need a separate product to create an installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no of software out to do it, Check [them](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/java-concepts/34-core-java/63-make-an-installer-for-your-java-applications.html) out